# What is the issue with the following code?

Tags: c

I am learning C on my own but this code which seems right to me doesn't works right

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    char name[20];
    int p,c,m;
    printf("Enter your name \n");
    scanf(" %s", name);
    if ( (name=='luv') || (name='pranav') )
    {
        printf("Enter your marks in pcm \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("get lost");
    }
    getch();
}
```

I want the correct code to run only if I enter name as `luv` or `pranav` but instead what is happening is that no matter whatever name i type it is running the code under else and i am not able to figure out the reason.

I am using codeblocks as compiler.

Comment: Also, your indentation is a problem. At least for me..

Comment: `getch` is not standard. Use `getchar`. And Code::Blocks is not a compiler!

Comment: Also CodeBlocks is not a compiler, it's an IDE. GCC and Clang are compilers.

Comment: Funny "problem" word is not allowed in title...

Comment: @P0W: Likely because it is redundant. But the edit is not more useful (as is the rest of the question).

Comment: Start reading a C book. Section "arrays and strings".

Comment: Too basic a question, able to fix after reading a little c text systematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `main()` is not a standard signature. You should use standard `int main(void)` unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.
- `'luv'` and `'pranav'` are multiple-character character constant, which have implementation-defined values. You should use string literals and `strcmp()` function.
- `name='pranav'` is an assignment, and you cannot assign to what is converted from arrays, so this will emit compile error.
- You should limit the length to read in order to avoid buffer overflow.

Try this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char name[20];
    int p,c,m;
    printf("Enter your name \n");
    scanf(" %19s", name);
    if ( (strcmp(name, "luv") == 0) || (strcmp(name, "pranav") == 0) )
    {
         printf("Enter your marks in pcm \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("get lost");
    }
    getch();
}
```

remove `#include <conio.h>` and `getch();` if they are not supported.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot compare strings using `==`, to compare strings, one has to use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

[`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) returns `0` when the strings are same, other wise it returns the difference of those two strings,

So essentially, your code would become,

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  // for the strcmp() function

main()
{
char name[20];
int p,c,m;
printf("Enter your name \n");
scanf(" %s", name);

// strings are given inbetween double quotes
// characters are given inbetween single quotes
if ( !(strcmp(name, "luv")) || !(strcmp(name, "pranav")) )
{
        printf("Enter your marks in pcm \n");
}
      else
    {
        printf("get lost");
    }
getch();
}
```

---

**NOTE:** 
1) Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

2) Check the return of functions like `scanf()`.

Comment: can you correct the code?

Comment: @Luv, use `strcmp` instead of `==`, that's all

Comment: Well, also double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: You are aware the code does not compare strings, but integers with pointers, are you?

Comment: `\\ for the strcmp() function` is invalid. Use `//` instead of `\\`.

Comment: @Olaf, Did not get you.

Comment: `luv` etc. have type `int`. They are not even strings. And the array names are converted to pointers, of course.

Comment: @Olaf, ??? `"luv"` is a string constant..!!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the apostrophs and should have clarified I meant the **original** code. From the original code: `(name=='luv')`.

Comment: @Olaf, Ok. try aiming your comments to particular people, (in this case the OP). That will avoid confusions like this one.

Comment: @Haris: I originally referred to your initial sentence "You cannot compare strings using `== `...". Anyway, you are right I should have made that more clear with the first comment. Sorry, not my best day today.

Comment: @Olaf, Well, I did that because I guessed the obvious intention of the OP is to compare strings. Anyways, no issues. no apologies needed.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of mistakes in the code.

I am trying to fix and show:

```cpp
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>   // to use strcmp
int main(void) // int and void added
{
    char name[20];
    int p,c,m;
    printf("Enter your name \n");
    scanf("%19s", name);  // no space before % and 19 to limit input
    if ( !strcmp(name,"luv")    // " instead of ' , and strcmp with operator !
        || strcmp(name,"pranav") == 0 )   // instead of ! you can use == 0 
    {
        printf("Enter your marks in pcm \n");
    }
     else
    {
        printf("get lost");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- Single quotes are used for character constants, not string constants.  You need to use double quotes for those.
- Strings can't be compared with `==`.  What you're actually doing is comparing the address of the first element of `name` with a character constant.  Even if you fixed the quotes on the constant, you'd be comparing the address of `name` with the address of a string constant, which are not the same.  To compare strings, you use `strcmp`, which compares each character in the string.

So what you want is this:

```
if ( (strcmp(name,"luv") == 0) || (strcmp(name,"pranav") == 0) )
```

You'll also need to `#include <string.h>` to use `strcmp`.